# Jquery find all images on a website link

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an jquery "inside" bookmarklet to my website like facebook share.

I need to get all images on a link. I mean if I give www.domain.com in my form, ajax request is needed to get all image links in that webpage and images should be shown in the form to select by user.

I'm sure there is a jquery plugin in order to do this, but I couldn't find any. I hope anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this for the actual site where the script will reside. The following code will get you all images.

```
$('img')
```

---

> I mean if I give www.domain.com in my form, ajax request is needed to
>   get all image links in that webpage and images should be shown in the
>   form to select by user.

No, you can't do this for a remote site. It's restricted by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You would be able to do this if you fetched the remote page with a server side handler on the same domain jQuery code will reside.

Comment: So if I get remote page content with php, I can catch all links via $('img') tag. thank you for answer Shef

Comment: @MattDagger Yes, if you get the content with PHP, then you can make an ajax request on your domain to get the content and parse it with jQuery. However, I would recommend you look into something else, like [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to look for images on the server side. That will make your image parsing a little faster, but will add load to your server.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for html parse script. I already use PHP simple HTML DOM Parser script [link](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) , I think it is also doing same job. thanks for great help

Comment: @MattDagger You are welcome. I suggested phpQuery, because it's a port of jQuery to PHP. Since you were looking for a solution in jQuery, I made the assumption you were much more familiar with the jQuery's selectors etc..., but whatever works for you. :)

Comment: wow after I've checked wiki examples finally I get the idea. It's quite useful like you said. you made my day :)